# SQL Server stored proceedure getting inserted ID and using it in the next query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to pull the inserted ID from the first query and use it in my second query in order to update another table with that returned ID.

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQLQuery = 'DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(50); 
                 SET @ID = INSERT INTO 
                    NEW_Project (@val1) 
                 OUTPUT Inserted.ID 
                    VALUES (@val2);
                 UPDATE 
                    mLine 
                 SET 
                    projectID = @ID 
                 WHERE 
                    employeeID = @val3'
EXEC [dbo].[_chkQ] @SQLQuery
```

Currently I am getting this error when trying to do the above query:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INSERT'.

How should I go about doing this in the correct syntax?

Comment: 1. do the insert, 2. use function SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get last identity value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQLQuery = 'DECLARE @ID numeric(38,0); 
                 INSERT INTO 
                    NEW_Project (@val1) 
                 OUTPUT Inserted.ID 
                    VALUES (@val2);
                 SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
                 UPDATE 
                    mLine 
                 SET 
                    projectID = @ID 
                 WHERE 
                    employeeID = @val3'

EXEC [dbo].[_chkQ] @SQLQuery;
```

Comment: I fixed a couple of issues.

Comment: what does **numeric(38,0);** do?

Comment: That's the datattype returned by the function, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

You need to output to a table variable, and then extract the ID from there:

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQLQuery = 'DECLARE @ID_Table table (ID VARCHAR(50)); 
                 INSERT INTO 
                    NEW_Project (@val1) 
                 OUTPUT Inserted.ID INTO @ID_Table
                    VALUES (@val2);
                 DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(50) = (SELECT ID FROM @ID_Table );
                 UPDATE 
                    mLine 
                 SET 
                    projectID = @ID 
                 WHERE 
                    employeeID = @val3'
EXEC [dbo].[_chkQ] @SQLQuery
```

Comment: Thanks for another way to do this, Camden!

Comment: @StealthRT - Please note that SCOPE_IDENTITY is not the recommended way to do it, and can cause errors if there is a parallel execution plan, see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2019779/you-may-receive-incorrect-values-when-using-scope-identity-and-identit